# ¿Cómo puedo sumar datos de un array en php?

Tags: php, array

Buen día, tengo este array:

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(1) { ["cantidad"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(1) { ["cantidad"]=> string(1) "1" } [2]=> array(1) { ["cantidad"]=> string(1) "1" } }
```

De esta manera saco los datos del array, pero no sé como sumar la cantidad que llegan en el arreglo:

```
if (is_array($datos)==true and count($datos)>0) {
  foreach ($datos as $row) {
  $output[] = $row["cantidad"];
  }
}else {
$output= "0";
}
```

Comment: ¿has intentado com array_sum? https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-sum.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hice un ejemplo para sumar todas las cantidades.

```
<?php


$datos = [
    ["cantidad" => "1"],
    ["cantidad" => "1"],
    ["cantidad" => "1"]
];

$output = 0;

if (is_array($datos) && count($datos) > 0) {
    foreach ($datos as $row) {
        $output += $row["cantidad"];
    }
}

echo $output;

?>
```

Explicación:

Lo que hice fue poner la variable `$output` fuera de las condicionales y en el foreach quité que fuese un array y lo unico que hace es que se le van sumando todos los numeros que haya en las claves `cantidad` del array.

(en la función is_array no hace falta hacer comparación, ya que devuelve true o false y no hay necesidad de compararlo)